# How do I remove/disable the Chrome/Chromium notification-center system indicator?

Tags: google-chrome, indicator, chromium

After upgrading recently, I noticed that when running Chromium, there is a new bell icon in the system indicators area in the upper right. The menu gives the options as such:

- Chromium - notifications
- Do not disturb
- Do not disturb for one hour
- Do not disturb for one day

Are these options only available via the system indicators menu, or can I remove this icon from my view, and access the same options somewhere else? How would I go about removing this?

Comment: Can you try going into settings and disable running background apps?

Comment: I see the option for "Continue running background apps when Chromium is closed", but that is already unchecked.

Comment: What version of ubuntu and chromium are you using? I don't see a bell shaped icon in the system indicators area on 14.04 using chromium 34.0. Also, which desktop manager are you using(unity, gnome, KDE, etc)?

Comment: @Jobin The notification icons where added with chrome/ium 35.x.

Answer (score 15):

Open the URL *chrome://flags* in the browser. Now disable these flags:

- #enable-sync-synced-notifications
- #enable-google-now
- #device-discovery-notifications
- #enable-experimental-notification-ui (Chrome/Chromium 34 only)

Click the restart button at the bottom of the site.

Comment: I tried disabling only google-now option but the notification came back again... After disabling all these above, there is no notification icon any more... Thank you!

Comment: @MladenB. What happens when you set a YouTube video to full-screen? Does the icon reappear?

Comment: @Glutanimate, I just tested with YT and the icon doesn't reappear.

Comment: @MladenB Ok, thanks for looking into that. It does reappear for me, strangely enough. Looks like it's quite temperamental.

Comment: @Glutanimate, it might be completely unrelated, but try to disable the option "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" in the Chrome's Settings page.

Comment: @MladenB. I already had that option disabled, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Glutanimate that's supposedly a bug (can't find the link right now). So the next update should fix this.

Comment: @mniess Yeah, I hope so, too. BTW, I am pretty sure only the `enable-google-now` flag controls the indicator. The other flags are placebos .

Comment: For me YT fullscreen brings the icon bag, regardless of changing these flags.

Comment: @king_julien as I wrote above: that's a bug that will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: @mniess Yeah, I meant to reply to Mladen B. Anyway, I just noticed this is not even just YouTube, but full screen flash videos in general.

Comment: I have none of those flags but I have notifications. Also, no tray icon. Just the popups.

Comment: @LtWorf Disabling the following flag might help: `#enable-native-notifications`.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

I found a very hackish but surefire way to hide the panel indicator.

Simply replace the stock indicator with [this one-pixel transparent PNG file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW97m.png) (*right click* → *Save link as* to download the file).

Instructions on replacing the indicator may be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/470691/81372).

**Original answer**:

---

There are various discussions about this on Google's product forums. The only solution I've found that partially works is to disable Google Now in Chrome's flags:

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags/#enable-google-now`
2. Set the flag to *Disabled*
3. Restart Google Chrome

However, even with this flag disabled the notification icon can reappear under some circumstances:

> The Notification Bell seems to reappear consistently when i fullscreen
>   a Youtube Video, even after deactivating "Google Now" and anything
>   that even mentions "Notifications" in the flags settings.

--- [Source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/itVC4OKfFsA/wuRwLmHFpgkJ)

Google's official statement on the matter isn't very satisfactory, either:

> Hi All,
>
> As mentioned on the flags page, those are experimental tools that can
>   get removed at any time. We are working on improving the notification
>   system and your options around controlling when to see them, which
>   will be included in upcoming releases. For Windows users, please try
>   clicking on system tray, customize link, which will open your control
>   panel. You can then change the settings for your notification area
>   icons for Chrome from there.
>
> - Sarah

--- [Source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/babyOtRtMuw/gb1MMtMyBn0J)

I guess we will have to wait for now.