# Disable Chrome's new notification icon

Tags: google-chrome, indicator

Yesterday I noticed a Google notification indicator when Google Chrome updated to Version 35.0.1916.114.

[image: g]

How can I remove it and stop Google from changing my desktop like that?

Comment: Google isn't really "changing your desktop"; they're just adding an icon to the desktop. There isn't any OS that requires a special permission to add an icon to the desktop.

Comment: Don't think there's anything you can do about it. You could however try dev channels of Google Chrome and Chromium. I do not have this "feature" and I use google-chrome-unstable...

Comment: Please see with `dpkg -l | grep indicator` if any package seems to indicate something that could lead to Chrome.

Comment: @MrVaykadji looks like it is hard-coded into chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [How do I remove/disable the Chrome/Chromium notification-center system indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460069/how-do-i-remove-disable-the-chrome-chromium-notification-center-system-indicator)

Shortly, try this.

Open the URL `chrome://flags` in the browser.

Now disable these flags:

- `#enable-sync-synced-notifications`
- `#enable-google-now`
- `#device-discovery-notifications`
- `#enable-experimental-notification-ui` **(Chrome/Chromium 34 only)**

Click the restart button at the bottom of the site.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/474048/178596

Comment: As with the duplicate's second answer, even if I disable the notifications you mentioned, the indicator still comes back. For example when putting a youtube video to fullscreen will make the indicator appear as mentioned by the second answer.

Comment: Please also note the `#enable-native-notifications` flag, which might help remove desktop notifications.

Answer (score 1):

On my Xubuntu I right-clicked on *xfce4-indicator-plugin* then clicked on *Settings* and there is something like *Remove Known Indicators*. I have system in different language so it could be named differently. But actially I dont use *xfce4-indicator-plugin* at all so be careful it can remove something else too.