# How to turn off Chrome notifications?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, with Google Chrome I have problem with these journal and Facebook notifications that pop up all the time. I have set up content settings, do not allow any site to show notifications. What should I try next?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already tried Google's directions?

> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the upper right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome
>      menu Chrome menu.
> 3. Click **Settings** > **Show advanced settings**.
> 4. In the "Privacy" section, click **Content settings**.
> 5. In the dialog that appears, go to "Notifications" and choose one of
>      the following:
>
>    - **Allow all sites to show notifications**: You’ll automatically see notifications from all websites.
>    - **Ask when a site wants to show notifications**: You’ll get an alert from Chrome whenever a site wants to show you notifications. This is
>        the default setting.
>    - **Do not allow any site to show notifications**: You won’t see any notifications from websites.

## If so, then you should follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/474437/518562) answer and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/473416/518562) answer.