# How can I resize icons on the system tray?

Tags: unity, icons, indicator, system-tray

**My system tray now** :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGep6.jpg]

Zeal, Spotify, google notifications, skype and many more apps that they have a app indicator by default, has a horror icons with over size.

I searched on google, ask ubuntu and others, but nothing.

I want the icons to display like below:

**Perfect result, but how?** :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZzU7.png]

How I can configure for get this result?

I'm at ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity.

I tried with `dconf` as well without result.

Please, help me and thanks for all!

Comment: only the systray is like that? you sure it isnt a graphichs driver bug?

Comment: Yes, icons on the left side or 'Alt+Tab' shows good quality, in Dash panel (using press: 'Super') as well. I'm working with AMDX64 - APU10-5800K (Integrated graphics), but in my old computer (AMD x64 single core). Ubuntu shows the same problem :S    Graphic bug...? I think not.

Comment: The default icons for time/network/volume/etc look fine in the original so it could be something to do with the fiddling you've done with dconf? Short of suggesting doing a reinstall, can you boot your computer with a live CD/USB to see if the systray look okay (and perhaps even install a couple of the other applications to see what their icons look like).

Comment: Not a solution, but: Most of the applications you mentioned use [sni-qt](https://launchpad.net/sni-qt) to draw the notification indicator. Might be where the fault lies. Your Chrome notifications indicator is completely fine, btw. That's just how it looks by default. [You can modify the icon, but it's quite an involved procedure](http://askubuntu.com/q/470691).

Comment: Well, first, thaks for all the answers but I think that the problem is on Ubuntu (Unity) because I'm testing now with ElementaryOS 0.2 (Luna) and the icons display so: http://i707.photobucket.com/albums/ww79/DNELART/5.png except Skype, all others are perfect. Ideas? except change the OS for eOS?