# How do I change Google Chrome's system tray icon?

Tags: unity, gnome, google-chrome, icons, panel

I'm very meticulous about how my desktop looks, and using Google Chrome as my main browser, I'm annoyed by certain inconsistencies in the icons that are in my panel.

[image: screenshot of top bar]

As you can see in the screenshot above, I'm using a very nice flat icon theme (derived from material design), and the icon that Chrome provides for its applet clashes horribly. It's an eyesore for me to say the least, so I'm looking for a way to replace (or at least mask) the icon.

In `/opt/google/chrome`, I found a bunch of image files named respectively as:

```
product_logo_256.png
product_logo_128.png
product_logo_16.png
product_logo_22.png
product_logo_24.png
product_logo_32.png
product_logo_32.xpm
product_logo_48.png
product_logo_64.png
```

which contain the stock Google Chrome icon at different resolutions.

I tried replacing these images with images of my own, from the icon pack I'm using, in an attempt to change the panel icon. However, upon closing all chrome processes and reopening the browser, the icon remained unchanged. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to change the icon so I can have a little more uniformity in my desktop environment?

Comment: I think there is a icon under `/usr/share/pixmaps` or something that is for the tray icon.

Comment: @Wilf I don't see any icons pertaining to Chrome under that directory, if I add the desired icon, would you know what it should be named as?

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470691/how-can-i-replace-google-chromes-low-resolution-notification-icon  ??

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470691/how-can-i-replace-google-chromes-low-resolution-notification-icon?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

There are also Chrome icons in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/NxN/apps/google-chrome.png`

`NxN` are various resolutions; you probably need to replace the image in either 22x22 or 24x24.

Comment: I replaced all the google-chrome.png icons in those directories with my desired icon (at the correct resolutions) and logged out and back in with no luck. Upon restarting Chrome, the tray icon remains unchanged :\

Comment: @uglytoaster Try

    `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor`

Comment: still no luck unfortunately