# How to change the ugly chrome/chromuim tray icon

Tags: google-chrome, icons, indicator, chromium

I'm writing a script to fix hardcoded indicator icons, and i'm having a problem fixing the google chrome/chromium indicator icon.

There's two icons that are shown in the tray; i managed to fix the bell one by modifying the `chrome_100_percent.pak`, but i couldn't change the Chrome/Chromium logo one. There's three icons in the same `chrome_100_percent.pak` file, changing them does not change the indicator icon, neither changing the icons in `/opt/google/chrome`.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: use [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher) it may assist you. also look at [same issue's solution](http://superuser.com/questions/460247/how-do-i-change-an-application-icon-on-ubuntu)

Comment: i mentioned that the icon is hardcoded.

Comment: Have you checked this icons: `dpkg -L google-chrome-stable | grep -P 'png|jpg'`

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470691/how-can-i-replace-google-chromes-low-resolution-notification-icon?lq=1

Comment: @ElderGeek i know how to fix this icon, i only need to fix the logo one ;)

Comment: I would assume it's in the resource.pak you didn't open. Some limited info on where to obtain info on how to do so is found here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/YzWbU5fwNgI    I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this in my script; https://github.com/bil-elmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu install, I see a bunch of icons here

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/XXxXX/apps/google-chrome.png
```

Where XXxXX are as follows

> 128x128
>
> 16x16
>
> 192x192
>
> 22x22
>
> 24x24
>
> 256x256
>
> 32x32
>
> 36x36
>
> 48x48
>
> 512x512
>
> 64x64
>
> 72x72

I would say the ones you need to modify are probably one these sizes

> 16x16
>
> 22x22
>
> 24x24

Close Chrome/Chromium
Try modifying/replacing one of them, and then run the following

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

I also see a large icon-theme.cache cache in /usr/share/icons/hicolor/, that may need to be refreshed if the above did not refresh it.

I checked my other computer that has Mint 17.2 install, and I see the same files in the same locations.

Comment: Those are not indicator icons :/ But i will give it a try; as i said before, the Google chrome indicators are hardcoded in a binary file but i couldn't find the file :/

Comment: Google Chrome does not install files in these folders.

Comment: Maybe you have installed Chrome from the source?Any customization?
These are the default locations for the standard install.

Comment: I don't have those files too. But i didn't try to add them by myself, i will do this weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of the command below to list all installed images by the packages `google-chrome-stable`, `google-chrome-unstable`, `google-chrome-beta`

```
dpkg -l | awk '/google-chrome-/ {print $2}' | xargs -i'{}' dpkg -L {} | grep -P 'png|jpg'
```

Example output

```
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_32.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_22.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_128.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_48.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_64.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_16.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_256.png
/opt/google/chrome-beta/product_logo_24.png
```

These icons are used in the tray. You can check it, [if you trust me](https://askubuntu.com/a/649244/367165), with the next command. The command removes all the icons.

```
dpkg -l | \
    awk '/google-chrome-/ {print $2}' | \
    xargs -i'{}' dpkg -L {} | grep -P 'png|jpg'  | \
    sudo xargs rm
```

After that kill all chrome processes and  restart Chrome again. It appears no icon.

Now install Chrome again via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-…
```

and customize your icons. **:)**

Comment: I've already tried to change those icons but that does not change the indicator icons :/

Comment: If you delete the icons, you have still an icon in the tray?

Answer (score 0):

I believe from when I used 14.04, and this may apply, that you can either go the the properties menu (easy way) and replace the image with an image file you have, or you can do it with the terminal (the intermediate way).

Please look at the text above me by 2 comments for the correct code (if it's correct, why do I need to restate it), or you can use the properties menu method, select and image, and save your changes. However, when you get updates, the image in the store will remain the same (unlike the other where it changes it in the app store, you should still have the image showing up the same on your desktop and task-bar when you're looking at it.