# How To Enable Google Now in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, system-tray

My Google chrome/chromium version is 44 and Ubuntu version is 15.04. I have  the Google Chrome icon in the notifications area and Google App Launcher on my Ubuntu Unity launcher but the Google Now and Notification icon are missing from taskbar. How to enable it?

The following flags in chrome://flags are missing

enable-sync-synced-notifications

enable-google-now

device-discovery-notifications

enable-experimental-notification-ui

Comment: You’ll only see the Notification Centre icon when there are messages waiting to be read.

Comment: @Ron Yes, I am getting the notification in android/windows but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: @dhiya please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/460069/how-do-i-remove-disable-the-chrome-chromium-notification-center-system-indicator).....Still I'm trying....but you may get some idea